# $\int_L (xe^x-x^2y)dx+(xy^2+\ln(1+y)dy$ dependency of path

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Does the line integral $\int_L (xe^x-x^2y)dx+(xy^2+\ln(1+y)dy$ dependent on specific path?

we were told that for $\int_Lfdx+gdy$, the integral is undependent of path if $\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{df}{dy}$, but here I have $\frac{dg}{dx}=-\frac{df}{dy}$, so is it still independent?

Comment: The correct condition is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, but even without that more fundamental error, you appear to have made a mistake in computing the partial derivatives.

Comment: Do you have any information on $L$? If $L = \partial D$ then Green's thm could help you...

Comment: Corrected. It was a typing mistake.

Comment: Why does the partial derivative wrong? I got the same

Comment: $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=y^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-x^2$ so it is not true that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$